# Compiling in geany but not in terminal?

Tags: python, opencv, serial-port

So I have been messing around with python with openCV the last couple of weeks and it has worked perfectly. My problem is when I took two desperate code script's and put them together it wouldn't compile. (I know Duh python white space (I fixed all of it,"I think")) It threw an error in the terminal with a line number. At this time I was using text editor in Ubuntu so I threw it into Geany to figure out what line. When I got there I couldn't pick out what the error was all of the indentation was that of the original code and it fitted with that of the rest of the loop it was nested in. So I tried to compile it in Geany and it didn't throw errors at all. I find this extremely weird because Geany is only an editor and it relies on outside compilers to compile the code. I am assuming that the terminal is using the same compilers too (though I know it must not now). I though maybe it has something to do with the library openCV because I am not including it in Geany. So I changed the variable name that was throwing things. After that it still threw the same error so I came here confused.

The error message I am getting is 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSXuM.jpg
My code is at
http://pastebin.com/HYKjnyyc
The part that is giving error is here
http://pastebin.com/6TyXs3uc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem still goes back to the white space you were working on.  Everything (except line 297 to the end) below:

```
# THE DEMO PROGRAM STARTS HERE
```

is indented, including your three global variables, which makes them appear to the compiler as part of the `class Target`, which takes the variables out of the global scope, so they are not defined.  Remove the unnecessary indentation in that area.

EDIT:
Looking back at your code again, You may also have some indentation problems from the

```
 #  Function Definitions
```

at line 88 and down. From the way the functions are indented they appear to be part of the class, but from the way they are called they appear not to be.

You would find writing in python a lot less frustrating if you use a more standard approach to your indentation/white-space handling. Read [this PEP](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for some best practices in that regard.